# Displaying Blank page in which PDF link is included

Tags: codenameone

Android OS version 7.1.1, following code display blank screen first time after download the App. Have to kill the App and open it again to work normally. Please advise.

[image]

Code:

```
Container cc = new Container(BoxLayout.y());
cc.setScrollableY(true);
TextArea ta = new TextArea(Util.readToString(is));
ta.setEditable(false);
ta.setUIID("Label");    
Button b = new Button("Terms of Service");
b.addActionListener(e3 -> {
try {
FileSystemStorage fs = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
final String homePath = fs.getAppHomePath();
String fileName = homePath + "Terms of Service.pdf";
Util.copy(Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/Terms of Service.pdf"), fs.openOutputStream(fileName));
Display.getInstance().execute(fileName);
} catch (IOException ex) {
}
});
cc.add(ta);
CheckBox rememberMe1 = new CheckBox();
rememberMe1.setSelected(false);
rememberMe1.setHeight(Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(10.0f));
rememberMe1.setAutoSizeMode(true);   
b.setAutoSizeMode(true);
setSameHeight(rememberMe1, l11, b); 
cc.add(FlowLayout.encloseIn(rememberMe1, b));
```

Comment: Do you see something in DDMS when this failure happens?